# How to set image for radtreeviewitem in wpf (by Telerik )

Tags: c#, wpf, telerik, radtreeview

I am using teleriks radtreeview control in my wpf application.Am adding treeviewitems (treenodes) in the treeview programatically .Now i need to set the imaghe for each treeviewitem programatically and i found that radtreeview sets the image by using these properties

> DefaultImageSrc
>
> SelectedImageSrc

**But my problem is only if i gave the full path of the image it works** . Its not possible in real time.So I need to map the images from the resources folder of my project .

```
RadTreeViewItem itm = new RadTreeViewItem();
itm.Header = "Demo";
itm.DefaultImageSrc = "/Resources/8.png";
itm.SelectedImageSrc= "/Resources/8.png";
trv.Items.Add(itm);
```

How to achieve it..??

Answer (score -1):

Your code seems to work just fine, assuming that `8.png` is in a Resources folder in your project, with the Build Action set to Resource.

You'll need to ensure you're adding the `RadTreeViewItem` to your `TreeView` too:

```
myTreeView.Items.Add(itm);
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. I am binding the value into treeview.My problem is not the item ,its the image next to the item.